# Is it wrong to use "we" as fans for something our team accomplished (or failed)?

Tags: pronouns

I and fellow fans: "We won! Yeah!!!!"

Devil's advocate: "No, you didn't! The [TeamName] won!"

What can be said about this?

Comment: This seems to be more a question of social norms than the English language.

Comment: I often cannot discern between the two. So usage of the word "we" I think is a language issue.

Comment: You can reply, "Don't be a such an a$$hole."

Comment: I agree this is more about social norms. There is nothing linguistically that prevents one from using the phrase and there's nothing incorrect about it if both parties to the conversation agree that `we` can refer to the grouping of the team with the fans. It's that last qualifier of "if both parties ... agree" that's important. Hence it's at broadest a matter of social norms, and possibly even depends on prior knowledge of the conversants.

Comment: Your devil's advocate is not claiming it's grammatically wrong, but that it's logically wrong. This is not a question about English, but about logic.

Comment: The next step is for you and your fellow fans to converge on the devil's advocate, chanting, ["You're not of the body! You're not of Landru!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m48xii7ndcg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sports teams may represent **schools, universities, companies, metropolitan areas, states,** or **nations**.  They are so designated in order to bond the members of the community they represent. In the recent World Series, the New York Mets played the Kansas City Royals.  Since I'm a New Yorker, I was upset when "we" lost the Series.  Of course I didn't play in it, but I did watch all the games; in fact, I watched most of the games in a 162-game season, plus most of the playoff games as well.  I felt that I had a stake in what happened.

Now imagine that it was just Mets against Royals, no regional designation, plus another two-dozen plus teams, also with no local affiliation.  No team has a home base, and all games (regular and post-season) are played in stadiums all over the country.  How would potential fans choose what team to align with?  And what if, in the bars and taverns in New York, everyone was rooting for a different team?  Municipalities would be less willing to provide first-class stadiums because fewer people would be interested in attending the games.  And the hometown spirit when a team wins would never materialize.

It's the belonging to the entity that the team represents that enables people to use **we** when talking about their local sports teams.